# Sharing 2 PC's, Windows 10 1903. Network share access shows up only on one or the other. Never both?

Tags: windows, networking, nfs

I don't understand why network access will show up on only one or the other PC never both.  Does it vary because of "something?"

Both machines have static internal IP's and are defined specifically in the hosts file. Password protected sharing turned off on both machines yet both required Windows account password to access the other.  Note they still vary which has access from day to day.  Services for NFS both Client and Administrative Tools are installed.

We have PC1 @ 192.168.1.103 and PC2 @ 192.168.1.104. Network through Tomato Netgear 7000. Both ping by IP and node name to each other. Then I added a direct network connection from machine to machine on separate NIC cards.  PC1 @ 169.254.2.103 and PC2 @ 169.254.2.104.  Now all IP's ping each other but Node Names PC1 & PC2 resolve to the 169.254.2.* subnet.  That seems reasonable to me as the PC's are defined to two specific IP's in the hosts file.

Why they resolve that way is a side question to me? Most curious though is one day all shares show up on PC1 or another day on PC2?

[ I'm next trying to discover how to direct large transfers through the 169.254.2.* subnet. ]

Comment: Are you sharing the folder via SMB or via NFS?

Comment: This seems like a racing condition. If you turn off both and boot only one, does it always show up? And if you then boot the second, does it show up?